# Sed Command that will check the 2nd column of my file and delete the matching data

Tags: unix, sed

I Would like to seek help, I'm a beginner using sed,

I want to delete the alphabets in the 2nd column using sed,  I'm also having problems with the header, since if its an alphabet it will remove the 2nd column of the header. The file is comma delimited.

```
address,salary 

manila,joan
manila,1111
manila,2222
manila,3334
```

It will remove the 'joan' row, so the output should be-:

```
address,salary

manila,1111
manila,2222
manila,3334
```

TIA

Comment: Could you explain about removing the 2nd column of the header? It is not clear from your post.

Comment: hi suspectus, all alphabets in the 2nd column should be removed,
not including the header, since my header 2nd column is an alphabet
from the example the manila | joan should be remove since joan is an alphabet not like the other 2nd column data

Comment: @user11916589 Please [edit] your question to add more information instead of answering in comments.

Comment: all alphabetical characters in the 2nd column *only* ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a job for `awk` rather than `sed`. Try using `awk` like this:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR == 1 || $2 !~ /[a-zA-Z]/' foo.txt
address,salary

manila,1111
manila,2222
manila,3334
```

If you really need to use `sed` for an in-place edit, try something like

```
$ sed -i '1b;/^[^,]*,[^,]*[a-zA-Z]/d' foo.txt
address,salary

manila,1111
manila,2222
manila,3334
```

Comment: hi jon, i have a csv file that needs to be modified, can i use awk to that?

Comment: @user11916589 I've added a `sed` example. It isn't pretty!

Comment: @user11916589 Your question is not clear. Do you mean that you want to modify the existing file? In this case you could use e.g. `awk -F, 'NR == 1 || $2 !~ /[a-zA-Z]/' foo.txt > foo.txt.tmp && mv -f foo.txt.tmp foo.txt || rm foo.txt.tmp`. If the answer doesn't fulfill a requirement which is not yet written in the question, then please add more information to your question.

Comment: hi Jon Thank you !! this resolve the problem !!